# Square API Search user by Email - endpoint is not supported in legacy Sandbox

Tags: php, square-connect, square

Going over [this documentation](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/customers-api/search-customers) I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the search feature to work and I'm getting an error:

```
$json = '{}';
$url = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/customers/search';
$curl_handle = curl_init($url);
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$request_headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen($json);
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,4) !== 'www.') {curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);}
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$json_response = json_decode($result,1);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

I get the following:

```
[category] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR
[code] => SANDBOX_NOT_SUPPORTED
[detail] => This endpoint is not supported in legacy Sandbox.
Learn more about the new Sandbox at https://developer.squareup.com/docs/testing/sandbox.
```

I'd like to be able to search by an email address. I tried using the JSON on the page though I still got the same error message. Ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ability to query a customer search by email address isn't currently available.